# Twilio: respond to prompt from incoming call with digit press with record

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have a twilio number. I would like to program a webhook for incoming calls to that number that handle the following scenario: the incoming call prompts the user to enter digits. I've tried using `<Play>` to send DTMF tones, but the subsequent transcription of the call doesn't indicate the tones had any effect. Here's the relevant part of the webhook endpoint

```js
const vr = new VoiceResponse();

vr.say('Hello');

vr.record({
  maxLength: 60,
  transcribe: true,
  transcribeCallback: '/voice/text',
});

vr.play({
  digits: 'wwww1',
});

vr.hangup();

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

return res.status(200).send(vr.toString());
```

The transcription reads along the lines of "Hello, for ____ press one, for ____ press two... Goodbye".

I would like to record subsequent parts of the call after sending digits. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The code looks right. Is it possible that you play the tones too early before the IVR accepts them?

Comment: I've tried different variations but without any other outcome. I thought I read in another post that if `<Record>` gets passed to `<Response>` it records the entirety of the call before carrying out any other verbs. If this is true I think I'll need to use the REST API to create a recording and try to access the transcript that way instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was with order of TwiML verbs. According to the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-action):

> Any TwiML verbs occurring after a `<Record>` are unreachable.

After modifying code to

```js
const vr = new VoiceResponse();

vr.say('Hello');

vr.play({
  digits: 'wwww1',
});

vr.record({
  maxLength: 60,
  transcribe: true,
  transcribeCallback: '/voice/text',
});

vr.hangup();

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

return res.status(200).send(vr.toString());
```

The IVR tree progression worked as expected.